# mysqli/PDO information: from mysqli to pdo-> how to handle error

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

I have finished the main functions of my code, but I have got tons of "useless" code that I'm trying to remove.
This is an example:

```
else if(isset($_POST['act']) && $_SESSION['status']<3 && $_POST['act']=='delete_ticket'){
    $encid=preg_replace('/\s+/','',$_POST['enc']);
    $encid=($encid!='' && strlen($encid)==87) ? $encid:exit();
    $mysqli = new mysqli($Hostname, $Username, $Password, $DatabaseName);
    $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
    if($stmt){
        $query = "UPDATE ".$SupportTicketsTable." a
                    INNER JOIN ".$SupportUserTable." b
                        ON b.id=a.operator_id
                    SET b.assigned_tickets= CASE  WHEN b.assigned_tickets!='0' THEN (b.assigned_tickets-1) ELSE b.assigned_tickets END  
                WHERE a.enc_id=?";
        if($prepared = $stmt->prepare($query)){
            if($stmt->bind_param('s', $encid)){
                if($stmt->execute()){
                    $query = "DELETE FROM ".$SupportMessagesTable." WHERE `ticket_id`=(SELECT `id` FROM ".$SupportTicketsTable." WHERE `enc_id`=?) ";
                    if($prepared = $stmt->prepare($query)){
                        if($stmt->bind_param('s', $encid)){
                            if($stmt->execute()){
                                $query = "SELECT enc FROM ".$SupportUploadTable." WHERE `ticket_id`=?";
                                if($prepared = $stmt->prepare($query)){
                                    if($stmt->bind_param('s', $encid)){
                                        if($stmt->execute()){
                                            $stmt->store_result();
                                            $result = $stmt->bind_result($mustang);
                                            if($stmt->num_rows>0){
                                                $path='../upload/';
                                                while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
                                                    if(file_exists($path.$mustang)){
                                                        file_put_contents($path.$mustang,'');
                                                        unlink($path.$mustang);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                            $query = "DELETE FROM ".$SupportUploadTable." WHERE `ticket_id`=?";
                                            if($prepared = $stmt->prepare($query)){
                                                if($stmt->bind_param('s', $encid)){
                                                    if($stmt->execute()){
                                                        $query = "DELETE FROM ".$SupportFlagTable." WHERE `enc_id`=?";
                                                        if($prepared = $stmt->prepare($query)){
                                                            if($stmt->bind_param('s', $encid)){
                                                                if($stmt->execute()){
                                                                    $query = "DELETE FROM ".$SupportTicketsTable." WHERE `enc_id`=?";
                                                                    if($prepared = $stmt->prepare($query)){
                                                                        if($stmt->bind_param('s', $encid)){
                                                                            if($stmt->execute()){
                                                                                echo json_encode(array(0=>'Deleted'));
                                                                            }
                                                                            else
                                                                                echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
                                                                        }
                                                                        else
                                                                            echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
                                                                    }
                                                                    else
                                                                        echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
                                                                }
                                                                else
                                                                    echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
                                                            }
                                                            else
                                                                echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                            echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                        echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
                                                }
                                                else
                                                    echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
                                            }
                                            else
                                                echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
                                        }
                                        else
                                            echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
                                    }
                                    else
                                        echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
                                }
                                else
                                    echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
                            }
                            else
                                echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
                        }
                        else
                            echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
                    }
                    else
                        echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
                    }
            else
                echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
            }
        else
            echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
    }
    else
            echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
}
else
    echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
exit();
}
```

As you can see there are too many `if` statement for the mysqli connection: this is the part I want to remove, is there a way remove them? I have tried to wrap it between `try` and `catch` but the code returns anyway the success `echo` (it's an AJAX call).
 I have read that mysqli have got some problems with try and catch function so I have took a look at PDO, but I'm not an expert  and I don't understan if I can get the same result of the code that I have posted with it, I have also read that I have to change the error mode to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`, but I haven't understood very well the point.
Basically: is there someone who can explain me how PDO handle the errors?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Because the question is pretty stupid or because the code is dreadful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, of all, your idea of sending mysqli error to the client is awfully wrong. Client has not a slightest idea what to do with it. So, you need some other way to handle errors.

I would say that just 500 response status is more than enough. You can check it with your AJAX code and show some excuses.

While the error message eiself have to be logged on the sertver side for your future reference.

Do you agree with such a setup?

Assuming you agree.

#### Mysqli approach #1:

You can change every

```
if(statement){
```

to

```
statement or trigger_error($mysqli->error);
```

like

```
$prepared = $stmt->prepare($query) or trigger_error($mysqli->error);
```

This way you will need no nested ifs: the very first mydsli error will abort the script execution.

#### Mysqli approach #2:

It is extremely good idea to create a wrapper function to call your queries like this

```
$query = "DELETE FROM ".$SupportMessagesTable." WHERE `ticket_id`=(SELECT `id` FROM ".$SupportTicketsTable." WHERE `enc_id`=?) ";
$db->query($query, $encid);
```

for this purpose you can use my [safeMysql library](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql). Here is an exemple with 2 first queries:

```
$query = "UPDATE ".$SupportTicketsTable." a
                INNER JOIN ?n b
                    ON b.id=a.operator_id
                SET b.assigned_tickets= CASE  WHEN b.assigned_tickets!='0' THEN (b.assigned_tickets-1) ELSE b.assigned_tickets END  
            WHERE a.enc_id=?i";
$db->query($query,$SupportUserTable, $encid);
$query = "DELETE FROM ?n WHERE `ticket_id`=(SELECT `id` FROM ?n WHERE `enc_id`=?i) ";
$db->query($query, $SupportUserTable, $SupportTicketsTable, $encid);
$query = "SELECT enc FROM ?n WHERE `ticket_id`=?i";
$mustang = $db->getOne($query, $SupportUserTable, $encid);
if($mustang){
```

and so on.

#### Explanation on exceptions

Exception is just a `petit mort` which stands for "little death" in French (literally. Though it has another, not so direct meaning). It is actually a local die(). It will terminate further script execution - **the exact purpose of your nested if's**, mind you.

So, while using PDO, you can write all your statements one under another **with no error checking**. PDO will perform it internally and throw an exception, thus terminating further execution.

An exception can be caught but it is not required. One may let it go and it will be converted to PHP error which can be logged.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand: in the first approach when I use `trigger_error($mysqli->error,E_USER_ERROR);` the error is saved inside error_log automatically? In this case I have to check with AJAX the response status? Why the second aproach can avoid the if statement, because inside the README he doesn't talk about error handling

Comment: That's good question. Although error handling is not mentioned it is implemented

Comment: In the end which one is your preferred?

Comment: Mysqli approach #2. though it could be complicated to adopt

Comment: One last question and then I have finished: does the performance difference between mysqli and PDO noticeable or it is just a matter of milliseconds(let's talk about a tables with 7-600k entries)?

Comment: Not even milliseconds. Absolutely unnoticeable

Comment: Feel free to ask any further questions